# Using actual regex in Ansible's search_regex parameter

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use the `wait_for` module in Ansible to repeatedly check a log file and end when it finds either success (the word **Successfully** appears in the log) or failure (the string **[FATAL]** appears in the log).

```
- name: Wait for Logstash API Endpoint to be running
wait_for:
  path: /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log
  search_regex: '(\\[FATAL\\]|Successfully)'
  delay: 30
  timeout: 120
```

I've tried various approaches to the `search_regex` parameter including no escape characters, single escape characters etc.

I've checked that the logs' output includes `[FATAL]` and it definitely does, but I can't get this module to work.

Where am I going wrong?

** **EDIT** **

Attempting to use the following code:

[image: regex]

On the following log:

[image: log output]

````
[2019-01-15T15:43:14,735][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.5.2"}
[2019-01-15T15:44:00,534][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::OrgLogstashConfigIr::InvalidIRException", :message=>"Config has duplicate Ids: \nID: jsonfilter P[filter-json{\"id\"=>\"jsonfilter\", \"source\"=>\"message\", \"remove_field\"=>[\"_sourceUri\", \"_user\", \"sourceUri\", \"user\", \"pid\", \"v\"]}|[str]pipeline:41:7:```\njson {\n        id => \"jsonfilter\"\n        source => \"message\"\n        # remove some irrelevant fields\n        remove_field => [\"_sourceUri\", \"_user\", \"sourceUri\", \"user\", \"pid\", \"v\"]\n      }\n```]\nP[filter-json{\"id\"=>\"jsonfilter\", \"source\"=>\"message\", \"remove_field\"=>[\"_sourceUri\", \"_user\", \"sourceUri\", \"user\", \"pid\", \"v\"]}|[str]pipeline:191:7:```\njson {\n        id => \"jsonfilter\"\n        source => \"message\"\n        # remove some irrelevant fields\n        remove_field => [\"_sourceUri\", \"_user\", \"sourceUri\", \"user\", \"pid\", \"v\"]\n      }\n```]", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.graph.Graph.validate(org/logstash/config/ir/graph/Graph.java:294)", "org.logstash.config.ir.PipelineIR.<init>(org/logstash/config/ir/PipelineIR.java:52)", "java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java/lang/reflect/Constructor.java:423)", "org.jruby.javasupport.JavaConstructor.newInstanceDirect(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaConstructor.java:246)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(org/jruby/RubyClass.java:1022)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(org/jruby/RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.compiler.compile_sources(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:29)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.compiler.RUBY$method$compile_sources$0$__VARARGS__(usr/share/logstash/logstash_minus_core/lib/logstash//usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(org/jruby/RubyClass.java:899)", "org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.callMethod(org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:372)", "org.logstash.config.ir.ConfigCompiler.configToPipelineIR(org/logstash/config/ir/ConfigCompiler.java:32)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt.initialize(org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:149)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$3$0$initialize.call(org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$3$0$initialize.gen)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline.initialize(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:22)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline.initialize(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:90)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(org/jruby/RubyClass.java:1022)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(org/jruby/RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.block in execute(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:42)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:289)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call19(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:273)", "org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call19.call(org/jruby/RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call19.gen)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.block in exclusive(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:92)", "org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex.synchronize(org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:148)", "org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex$INVOKER$i$0$0$synchronize.call(org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex$INVOKER$i$0$0$synchronize.gen)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.exclusive(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:92)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$method$exclusive$0$__VARARGS__(usr/share/logstash/logstash_minus_core/lib/logstash//usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.execute(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:38)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$__VARARGS__(usr/share/logstash/logstash_minus_core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action//usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb)", "usr.share.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.block in converge_state(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:317)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:289)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:246)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:748)"]}
[2019-01-15T15:44:01,189][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::OrgLogstashConfigIr::InvalidIRException` for `PipelineAction::Create<main>`>, :backtrace=>["org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:103:in `create'", "org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:34:in `add'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:329:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2019-01-15T15:44:02,220][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
````

Results in this failure:

[image: failure]

Further info:

[image: additional debugging]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing you were soooooooooo close. This:

```
search_regex: "(\\[FATAL\\]|Successfully)"
```

works for me. (Note " rather than ')

Also, check that Ansible has permission to read the log file. In the case that it doesn't, `wait_for` doesn't give you any indication that it can't read the file.

Comment: Hi @clockworknet, thanks for this. I've tried your code and it doesn't appear to work for me. Updating my OP now with screenshots.

Comment: Hmm - not sure what to suggest. The code (with double quotes) definitely works for me. I have tested using a similar string to the one in your screenshot (if you want to add the actual log fragment to the question, rather than screenshot, I will test with it). What version of Ansible are you using? Is it possible there is any unusual file encoding going on with the log file `file -i /path/to/log`

Comment: Have added the log for testing purposes, will add the file command now.

Comment: Yep - that works for me also. Do the permissions on the path to the log file allow the user the Ansible process is running as to read the logfile? I just tried in the case that they don't, expecting the task to fail with an appropriate error. It doesn't. :( As an aside, `wait_for` can also poll for a port, so you could alter the task to simply wait on port 9600 (or whatever port you have configured) to open, if it will bind to lo as well as the  external interface.

Comment: Your port suggestion sounds sensible - I might investigate that. I don't think there are any problems with the file because if I change the `search_regex` field to just `[FATAL]`, it works perfectly. It's only when I try to use actual regex that it fails. Going to add another screenshot to my OP with the output of the `file -i` command.

Comment: Interesting. In my case the charset of the logfile is `charset=us-ascii`. My guess would be that the file encoding `charset=binary` is tripping this up.